# Remove block from Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2.2

I have a custom theme which was working fine on 2.1.9.

Just upgraded to 2.2 and noticed some blocks I used to remove are now in place.

> app/design/frontend/MyThemes/custom1/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true" />
```

I have already removed var & pub/static contents, also deployed static content through

```
setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
In more recent versions of Magento2, the remove method is now:
```

Example:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceBlock name="block_name" remove="true"/>
  </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I´m using this same sintax, but somehow it seems their names were changed since they stopped working: